# trying to change nav tabs active class within a modal on click of separate buttons bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, meteor

I have nav tabs within a modal as shown. I am using the meteor framework.

Here is the modal link from sign up button (there is another button called login that links to same modal):

```
<button class="btn btn-primary full-width center-text" data-toggle="modal" id="signUpModalButton" data-target="#signUpModal">SIGN UP</button>
```

If the model is called from sign up button, I want signup tab within modal to be active
If the model is called from login button, I want login tab within modal to be active

```
<div class="modal autoModal" id="signUpModal" tabindex="-1" data-keyboard="false"
       role="dialog" aria-labelledby="signUpModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
          <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-body">
                  <!-- Nav tabs -->
                  <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist" id="signUpLogInTabs">
                    <li class="{{if clicked sign up this should say active"><a href="#signUp" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">SIGN UP</a></li>
                    <li class="{{if clicked login in this should say active}}"><a href="#login" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">LOG IN</a></li>
                  </ul>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Consider [this](http://robertdickert.com/blog/2014/05/09/set-up-navigation-with-iron-router-and-bootstrap/) tutorial that avoids mixing classes and take a Handlebars alternative.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add or remove class on each button's click:

```
$('#signUpModalButton')
  .on('click', function() {
      $('li:first-child').addClass('active');
  });
$('#logInButton')
  .on('click', function() {
      $('li:last-child').addClass('active');
  });
```